# Summing custom labeled cells in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet that I'm calculating particular costs.  These costs have associated labels to them: Manufacturing, Variable, Both, Neither.  I have created a drop down list for next to the costs that selects these categories, what I want to do is in a separate cell, calculate the sum of costs based on the labels: (to calculate variable costs i need to add categories Variable **and** both, etc).  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SUMIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) should work just fine for this.

Let me know if you need suggested syntax.

Comment: Glad it helped!